# Digital Signal Processing with Android's SoundPool

Tags: android, signal-processing, soundpool

I'm looking to create an app that mimics a guitar amp's signal processing. Specifically, I want to give users a set of dials or sliders that allow them to fine tune the way notes played in the app sound when they are output. For example a user may want their notes to sound like they are playing metal, or jazz, or blues etc. My goal is to implement this functionality using baseline audio files that can be tweaked to produce any tonal variant a user desires. Using the SoundPool in Android, how possible is this?

Comment: Show us something you have tried. Your question needs to address a specific problem. You are asking for the whole code !

Comment: I am absolutely not asking for the whole code. My question clearly addresses a specific problem: is signal processing possible using the SoundPool. I haven't tried anything because I don't know how this would be accomplished, if it can even be accomplished at all. There are no tutorials I've found online regarding this. I'm not sure what else I can do here; I'm asking if something is possible or not, very straightforward question.